# Does Sdl.Web.Delivery work with ASP.NET Core?

Tags: iis-and-asp.net, mvc

I am trying to build a web site on ASP.NET Core (formerly known as MVC 6) on .NET Framework 4.7. This should work according to Microsoft (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-core-2-0/).

However, if I reference Sdl.Web.Delivery on this project, only 4 files from the package are copied to the bin folder:

- Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.dll
- Tridion.ContentDelivery.dll
- Tridion.ContentDelivery.Preview.dll
- Tridion.ContentDelivery.UGC.dll

I'm missing all the DLLs that start with 'Sdl.Web' (like Sdl.Web.Delivery.Broker.dll, Sdl.Web.Delivery.Caching.dll, etc).

As a result, I cannot use the API at all.

If I do the exact same thing on an MVC 5 project based on the same .NET Framework, I get all the DLLs and everything works fine.

What could explain this?

Comment: Your building in Visual Studio? Anything wrote into the Output window when you build that might give a clue?